# Volume of a 'cylinder with rounded sides'

Tags: volume, solid-geometry

I need to find the volume of a torus-shaped object, but it which doesn't have space between the ring. 
We can find the volume of the ring, but what about the inner part?

PS: What is that shape called?

**EDIT:**
I've edited the title. What I mean, is a Cylinder, with rounded sides.

Comment: A torus isn't really "made out of something by drilling a hole", so it's hard to say exactly what you're looking for? Ellipsoids perhaps.

Comment: It sounds like a cylinder with rounded sides

Comment: By a donut without a hole, do you mean something like [this](http://www.prioryfinepastries.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/Cream-Filled-Donut.jpg)?

Comment: I should change the question a bit. I am talking about the space between the torus. I'm _not_ looking for ellipsoids. The space is flat, not curved. I hope you get it.

Comment: It would be like, first, calculating the volume of the Cylinder, then, adding half the volume of a congruent torus.

Comment: Not half, since the volume of the torus on the far side is more than the part that overlaps with the corresponding cylinder.

Comment: Do you mean [something like this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=volume+of+a+torus+with+a+%3D+1+and+c+%3D+0) ?

Comment: No @AakashM. Vrugtehagel has got it right.

Comment: @Perceptioner ah, the solid of revolution about the y-axis of an axis-aligned rectangle with semicircular caps on the left and right sides. Got you.

Comment: @Perceptioner Don't know if you are still interested, but I've given a somewhat different approach in my new answer (Apr 2017) below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that both of the previous answers are in agreement at this point, but unfortunately neither gives a method that readily lends itself to doing similar problems. That is, the are *ad hoc* solutions that solve only the one problem. A more general approach is to apply Pappus's ($2^{nd}$) Centroid Theorem: the volume of a planar area of revolution is the product of the area *A* and the length of the path traced by its centroid *R*, i.e., $2\pi R$.

Now, the centroid of a composite area is the weighted sum of the component centroids. Using subscripts *r* and *c* for the rectangular and circular parts, we have

$$R=\frac{A_rb/2+A_c(b+4a/3\pi)}{A}$$

where $A_c=2br$ and $Ac=\pi a^2/2$. Then, by Pappus's theorem

$$V=2\pi RA=2\pi \left[A_r\frac{b}{2}+A_c\left(b+\frac{4a}{3\pi}\right)\right]=\dfrac43 \pi a^3 + \pi a b ( \pi a + 2 b )$$

which is seen to be the same as @Narasimham. As a parity check, you can verify that

$$\pi b^2 2a<V<\pi (b+a)^2 2a$$

For your next challenge, find the volume of the disk or radius *b* with a half-torus cut out of it, as in railroad wheel.

Comment: Thanks, that's a neat solution! And that challenge of yours, I guess we could simply subtract area*(b - 4a/3pi) instead of adding, to find new centroid.

Comment: @Perceptioner I can agree with that, The point is that when you have a *method* everything falls into place. As an aside, my approach is always *why solve one problem when can solve them all*?

Answer (score 4):

Let $S$ be our shape. The picture below (made with [Pov-Ray](http://www.povray.org/)) illustrates $S$. It is the intersection of a torus (red) with a cylinder (blue, half-transparent).

[image: Torus-cylinder-intesection]

Furthermore, let $h$ be its height and $r$ be the radius at the top (so the radius at the middle is $r+h$) (see image below, made with Paint :$).

[image: Graph $R(x)$]

Now we call the radius at a given height $x$ the function $R(x)$ (where $x$ goes from $x=-\frac12h$, bottom, to $x=\frac12h$, top. See the graph above. $x$ is on the x-axis). Luckily the shape of a circle is easy, so we can compute $R(x)$ by $$R(x)=r+\sqrt{\tfrac14h^2-x^2}$$
So now we can calculate the volume by rotating $R(x)$ around the x-axis (see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_of_revolution#Disc_method) wikipedia article for more information about revolving an area between a curve and the x-axis):

\begin{align}\pi\int_{-h/2}^{h/2}R(x)^2
&=\pi\int_{-h/2}^{h/2}\left(r+\sqrt{\tfrac14h^2-x^2}\right)^2dx\\
&=\pi\int_{-h/2}^{h/2}\left(r^2+2r\sqrt{\tfrac14h^2-x^2}+\sqrt{\tfrac14h^2-x^2}^2\right)dx\\
&=\pi\left(\int_{-h/2}^{h/2}r^2dx+2r\int_{-h/2}^{h/2}\sqrt{\tfrac14h^2-x^2}dx+\int_{-h/2}^{h/2}|\tfrac14h^2-x^2|dx\right)\\
&=\pi\left(hr^2+2r(\tfrac12\pi\cdot \tfrac14h^2)+\int_{-h/2}^{h/2}\tfrac14h^2dx-\int_{-h/2}^{h/2}x^2dx\right)\\
&=\pi\left(hr^2+\tfrac14r\pi h^2+\tfrac14h^3-[\tfrac13x^3]_{-h/2}^{h/2}\right)\\
&=\pi\left(hr^2+\tfrac14r\pi h^2+\tfrac14h^3-\tfrac1{12}h^3\right)\\
&=h\pi\left(r^2+\tfrac14r\pi h+\tfrac16h^2\right)\\
\end{align}

Comment: Oh. i see why the volume of far part is greater. Thanks!

Comment: I will create and include an image later, so that the meant shape is clear to everyone

Comment: I'm getting quite different measures of volume using your formula and Narasimham's formula. I took r = 4 and h=2. I've got 144.19 using your formula, and 107.48 using Narasimham's.

Here's your formula http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Find+(pi)h((1%2F6)h%5E2%2Br%5E2%2B(1%2F4)(pi)(r)h)+where+h%3D2+and+r%3D4

And Narasimham's formula http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Find+(pi)a+((a%2F2)(b%2B((4a)%2F(3pi)))+%2B+2b%5E2)+where+a%3D1+and+b%3D4

Comment: @Perceptioner, I see. Strange. Unfortunately I have trouble following the steps Narasimham takes, and thus, I'll try to make my work as crystal-clear as I can, to be sure that I didn't make any mistakes.

Comment: Typing $ 2 \pi$  at second step forgotten, now corrected.

Comment: @vrugtehagel ; There is still an error in your last line. Is it ok last line (for discussion only ; OP's Wolfram Alpha calculation is correct) about indicated error in red? shall delete it after a while ...This is a comedy of errors. :))

Comment: @Narasimham, I can't seem to find my mistake. Can you explain it? If a mistake is made, then it is not made in the last calculation - the $\frac12$ is in the previous line, too. It didn't change in the last step

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Find+(pi)h((1%2F6)h%5E2%2Br%5E2%2B(1%2F4)(pi)(r)h)+where+h%3D2+and+r%3D4    ; your last line does not agree with what OP checked on Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: Right, @Narasimham, I found it. Finally, our answers agree.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are referring to the outer positive ( Gauss) curvature part of an anchor ring of following cross-section. There are two parts in it.

[image: Thickness rounded disc]

For rounded outer part Pappu's theorem is beneficial for estimating volumes of revolution.(case $b=0 $). But you should know the center of gravity of area before finding volume of rotated part.

Let us use the theorem to find position of area center of gravity of semi-circle at first.

$$ 2 \pi c \cdot \pi a^2/2 = 4 \pi a^3/3 $$

$$ c= \dfrac{4a}{3 \pi} $$

This wont change even when whole thing is pulled out radially $( b>0)$.

So, the volume of round part = $( \pi a^2/2) \cdot  \color{red}{2 \pi}\cdot( b+c)   $

EDIT1 :

( My earlier error of omission $ 2\pi $ )

Volume of central disk or cylinder = $ \pi b^2 ( 2a) $

Find total volume adding above two.

$$ \color{red} {V_{total} =  \dfrac43 \pi a^3 + \pi a b ( \pi a + 2 b )} $$

Comment: Check my comment on vrugtehagel's answer. I'm getting different measure using his equation.

Comment: @Narasimham, could you clearify your steps? I cannot quite follow your reasoning, and as the OP has pointed out, our answers do not give the same outcome. On of us is not right, so we'll need to figure out who of us it is.

Comment: We are both right.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like what you're looking for might be the volume of a [Superegg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superegg) which is a made by rotating a [superellipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superellipse) about it's central axis. The equation for a superellipse is: $$ \left|\frac{x}{a} \right|^n + \left| \frac{y}{b} \right|^n = 1. $$ For the kind of shape you're looking for, I would think you want an $n$ of 2 or greater (also called a "hyperellipse" or a "squircle") which generates a shape like this:

[image: Squircle]

Rotating this about it's central axis would create just the shape you're looking for.

Comment: Sorry but that's not what i mean.