# What is shape of a lifesaver?

Tags: geometry

I was wondering if there was a mathematical name for a shape that's similar to a rectangular prism or a cube, but every part side besides the top and bottom of it are round like a sphere, while the top and bottom are flat.

The first things that come to mind are a lifesaver (candy or lifebuoy) but with the whole filled in and the bread on a panini sandwich.

I couldn't figure out what terms to look for on Google, so what terminology would you use for this shape?

Edit: Probably easier to imagine a donut with the hole still in it.

Edit 2: Babybel Cheese is the closest thing I've seen:
[image]

Comment: Maybe you would like to draw approximately what it is in your mind and attach it here.

Comment: [Rounded cube?](https://www.google.com/search?q=rounded+cube&rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS907US907&sxsrf=ALeKk01RYYuaEjGvUfeim7uaEOlOEOxADw:1629304997891&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=9hPQkA8UsbWZIM%252Ca_6kOldTAjybqM%252C_&vet=1&usg=AI4_-kTJzVRd4Epl05BESX7NQ4bczDe7pQ&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwja0oSNgrvyAhWEKVkFHco3C1UQ9QF6BAgQEAE&biw=1536&bih=683#imgrc=9hPQkA8UsbWZIM)

Comment: @DonThousand Like a rounded cube, but the sides and corners COMPLETELY round. Ah! Like a Donut but with no hole.

Comment: [Attempt #2: Babybel cheese?](https://www.google.com/search?q=babybel+cheese&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwjT7uGLg7vyAhWzrHIEHRdjB3gQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=babybel&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQARgAMggIABCABBCxAzIICAAQgAQQsQMyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDoECCMQJzoECAAQQzoHCAAQsQMQQ1ClIVjgKmDuOWgAcAB4AIABTogB7QOSAQE3mAEAoAEBqgELZ3dzLXdpei1pbWfAAQE&sclient=img&ei=rzkdYZPbJ7PZytMPl8adwAc&bih=683&biw=1536&rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS907US907#imgrc=ozlkGezzCqUgdM)

Comment: This is a special case of a spherical segment, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_segment. I can't find any more specific name for it, however.

Comment: @DonThousand Yep! Just like Baybel cheese.

Comment: Perhaps fillet / chamfer of a cube. You could call it a ['dilation'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilation_(morphology)) or Minkowski sum with a sphere.

Comment: Perhaps you have in mind the convex hull of a torus.

Comment: https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oblate_spheroid

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales This is super close, but without the hole in the center 

Comment: There is no hole in a convex hull.

Comment: @ZackPlauché the convex hull doesn't have a hole - it covers up the hole. [See also this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1647569/775158)

Comment: @WillJagy This is almost it, but the top should be flat. Unless the top can be flat as well, but the image in that one looks round on the top and bottom.

Comment: The top (and bottom) of the convex hull of the torus will be flat. To see this note that the set highest points  on a torus (that is lying flat on the plane) forms a circle. Taking convex hulls fills that circle into a flat disk that form the top of the hull.

Comment: @ZackPlauché IDK name but to define it let $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ be your base shape, make the cylinder $A \times [0,2]$ and union it with $(A \times \{1\}) + B(0,1)$